# Getting slope in Google Earth Engine of defined sets of points?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, point, extract-by-mask, google-earth-engine-python-api

I have an reclassify a slope in the, and I have points(ee_kaski) with lat,lng . I want to extract value of the reclassify slope value where this points lies on it. I have tried this using Python API.

My code is:

```
Map = geemap.Map(center=(28.2622,84.0167), zoom=12)
location = "users/landsatpractise/Kaski"
ee_kaski = ee.FeatureCollection(location)
#dem image
image = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003")
slopesmrt = ee.Terrain.slope(image).clip(ee_kaski)
slopereclass = ee.Image(1) \
          .where(slopesmrt.gt(0).And(slopesmrt.lte(7)), 9) \
          .where(slopesmrt.gt(7).And(slopesmrt.lte(15)), 6) \
          .where(slopesmrt.gt(15).And(slopesmrt.lte(22)), 4)
SlpopeViz = {'palette': ['ecd3f5', 'bf72db','a333cc','4a0463']}
Map.addLayer(slopesmrt,SlpopeViz)
#fire_data
fire_data = ee.FeatureCollection("users/landsatpractise/fire_location_required")
Map.addLayer(fire_data)
```

Map
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 functions for extracting data from an `ee.Image`, one is for individual geometries and the other for many geometries at the same time (feature collection). What you need is the latter.

```
fire_data_extracted = slopereclass.reduceRegions(
    collection=fire_data,
    reducer=ee.Reducer.first(),
    scale=30
)
# see some results
print(fire_data_extracted.limit(5).getInfo())
```